# how to fire back button to in the navigationcontroller modal dialog view

Tags: ios, objective-c

First View has a compose button that calls the composeview as modal dialog. I have added a cancel button to the second view. Where do I add the action for the cancel button?

```
ComposeTweetVC* composeViewController = [[ComposeTweetVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"ComposeTweetVC" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
UINavigationController *nvc = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:composeViewController];

UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton =
[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                 style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                target:nil
                                action:@selector(backPressed:)];

composeViewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newBackButton;

[self presentViewController:nvc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Where do I add the backPressed method? If I add to the viewcontroller calling the composeviewcontroller, it is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add it wherever you want.

Your problem is:

```
target:nil
```

You are essentially calling `[nil backPressed:]` which is a NOOP.

Try changing `nil` to `self` or `composeViewController`, or whatever object you want to be notified when the button is pressed.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you ! I feel like self should be in charge of dismissing the view since it created it in the first place. What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the target to `nil` so the `backPressed:` will never be called

try to change this line

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                            target:nil
                            action:@selector(backPressed:)];
```

to be

```
UIBarButtonItem *newBackButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                             style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                            target: composeViewController
                            action:@selector(backPressed:)];
```

Answer (score 0):

set your target

```
initWithTitle:style:target:action:
```

Initializes a new item using the specified title and other properties.

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title style:(UIBarButtonItemStyle)style target:(id)target action:(SEL)action
```

**Parameters**

**title**

The item’s title. If nil a title is not displayed.

**style**

The style of the item. One of the constants defined in UIBarButtonItemStyle.

**target**

**The object that receives the action message.**

**action**

The action to send to target when this item is selected.

and then use

```
-(void) backPressed:(id)sender{

  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
```